# Odeint graph plot of bz reaction not giving correct graph result

Tags: python, graph, odeint

I think the problem might be in 'func' but I cant find it. The graph I get is just a red line at 0. 
I'm trying to get the plot of z and y concentration over time for a Belousov–Zhabotinsky reaction.

```
 # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from __future__ import division
from numpy import linspace
from matplotlib import pyplot as plot
from scipy.integrate import odeint

k0 = 1.0*60.0
kR2 = (10.0**6.0)*60.0
kR3 = 2.0*60.0
kR4 = 2000.0*60.0
kR5 = 10.0*60.0
CH = 0.8 #[0]
CA = 0.04 #[1]
CB = 0.05 #[2]
CX = 0.0 #[3]
CY = 0.0 #[4]
CZ = 3.0*(10.0**4.0) #[5]
CP = 0.0

def func(c,t):
    ([(-(kR3*(CH**2)*c[0]*c[3])-(kR5*CH*c[0]*c[2])+(0.5*kR4*(c[2]**2))),
     (-k0*c[2]*c[4]),
     ((kR3*(CH**2)-(kR2*CH*c[2]*c[3])+(kR5*CH*c[0]*c[2])-(kR4*(c[2]**2)))),
     (-(kR3*(CH**2)-(kR2*CH*c[2]*c[3])+((1/3)*k0*c[1]*c[4]))),
     ((2*kR5*CH*c[0]*c[2])-(k0*c[1]*c[4])),
     ((kR3*(CH**2)+(2*kR2*CH*c[2]*c[3])+(0.5*kR4*(c[2]**2))))])


ti = linspace(0,20,1000)

Ci = odeint(func,[CA,CB,CX,CY,CZ,CP],ti)


plot.plot(ti,Ci[:,3],'r',ti,Ci[:,4],'b')
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the issue is that you forgot the "return" in func(c,t), for the moment it returns nothing:

```
def func(c,t):
    return [ bla bla bla]
```